# moving files older than one day

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am using the below script to move files older than a day to other directory, and I was just checking with an `echo` statement whether its working fine.

```
    for i in `ls -lhrt | grep TRACK`
    do
     for j in `$i | awk '{print $7}'`
     do
      if [[ $j -lt $((`date |  awk '{print $3}'` - 1)) ]];
       then echo $j less than $((`date |  awk '{print $3}'` - 1))
      fi
     done
    done
```

But I see some errors and the script is not working fine. If i do an `ls -lhrt | grep TRACK | awk '{print $7}'`, it works fine and returns the date ( the numerical field).

If I modify the script like:

```
    for i in `ls -lhrt | grep TRACK | awk '{print $7}'`
    do 
     if [[ $i -lt $((`date |  awk '{print $3}'` - 1)) ]]; 
      then echo $i less than $((`date |  awk '{print $3}'` - 1))
     fi
    done
```

It works fine though.

What is the exact logic I'm missing out in the original script?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do this with `find` with the `-mtime +1` or `-ctime +1` option.

Comment: @paul : That's right. But I just wanted to know what could be wrong with this particular script. Mant thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but your `for j` line is trying to execute whatever is in $i, and pass the output of that to awk. I suspect you meant to echo $i and pass that to awk.

Answer (score 2):

Your script works on the assumption that the first for loop (`for i in ...`) iterates on lines, but that assumption is wrong. If you add an `echo "$i"` in the body of the loop, you will see that it operates on words, not lines.

The next error has already been pointed out and is that in the line

```
for j in `$i | awk '{print $7}'`
```

the script tries to execute the content of the variable $i. You want to add an `echo` command here, like this:

```
for j in `echo $i ...
```

But of course this wouldn't solve your problem, because $i contains already single words and there will be no 7th word that awk could print.

A simple solution (if you insist on not using `find`) is indeed what you already wrote yourself:

```
for i in `ls -lhrt | grep TRACK | awk '{print $7}'`
```

But if you wish to keep both loops, you can change the special variable IFS (internal field separator) in the script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

OIFS="$IFS"
IFS="
"
for i in `ls -lhrt` ; do
  IFS="$OIFS"
  echo ">>$i<<"
  for j in `echo $i|awk '{print $7}'` ; do
    echo ">>$j<<"
  done
done
```

The line with `IFS="` contains nothing after the `"` the assignment ends on the next line with the single `"` and so assigns the line feed character to the IFS special variable. Be sure to restore IFS as soon as possible in your scripts. (If you fail to do that you will get very confusing behavior from the shell, as spaces no longer separate words...)

PS: You are aware that your script will fail every time when a new month starts?

PPS: You are aware that your script depends on the current locale? On my PC the 7th word of the lines is "Dez" at this time of the year, so I had to add an `LANG=C` when running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Just seen your update

```
$i | ...
```

will try to run an executable that is called whatever the value of `$i` is. In your case, this will work for $i = 1, 2 and 3 (but not do what you want it to) and fail otherwise.

You want to send the string to the next process in the pipe, not run an executable by that name. You need to do

```
echo $i | ...
```

Comment: No doesn't help. This doesn't yield any output

Comment: `echo $i` will simply break the line wherever it finds the space.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I'm giving is for general purpose . I know you asked for moving files only older one day but this solution move files in current directory according to given criteria. Shell script takes following parameters -
for general purpose I have named sh file containing shell script as "mymov"

1. First parameter can either be -O or -N. With -O, files older than the given date are moved. With -N, files newer than the given date are moved.
2. Second parameter is the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy. Files older or newer (depending upon the first parameter) than this date are moved.
3. Third parameter is name of a folder in the current directory where files are moved. This folder is created if not already existing.

Shell script mymov only moves files and DOES NOT move folders. After moving the files, shell script also displays total number of files moved and total number of files existing in the current directory.

Example:
c:\ABC> mymov  -O  05/08/2015  XYZ
Moves those files of current directory i.e. c:\ABC which are older than 05/08/2015 to the folder XYZ existing in c:\ABC . This folder is created if not already existing.

```
#! /bin/bash

instance=""
 
if [ $1 = "-O" ]
then
  instance="-gt"
else 
  instance="-lt"
fi

arr=$(ls)

inputDate=$2
dd=${inputDate:0:2}
mm=${inputDate:3:2}
yyyy=${inputDate:6:4}

dateQuery=$(date --date=$mm/$dd/$yyyy +'%s')
filename=`basename $0`

totalFiles=0
movedFiles=0

if [ -d $3 ]
then
  echo Directory exists
else 
  mkdir $3
fi

for file in $arr
do
  if [ -d $file ]
  then
    continue
  fi

  if [ $file = $filename ]
  then 
    echo Skipped Current File
    continue
  fi

  fileFormate=`stat --format=%Y $file`
  if [ $dateQuery $instance $fileFormate ]
  then

    mv $file $3
    ((movedFiles++))
    ((totalFiles++))
  else
    ((totalFiles++))
  fi
done

echo Total number of files moved = $movedFiles
echo Total number of files present = $totalFiles
```